# Template parse errors - Angular 5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, angular5, angular2-template

I've read and encountered this issue many times. I am not sure if this is related to Ang 5.I have tried to downgrade to 4. No Luck so far. Any thought.

From what I read, my attempt to resolve the below issue was to add in app.module.ts:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
```

**Error in console:**

[image: errors in console]

> " Property binding ngForIn not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations" .... "

this is my code

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      {{eventItem.title}}
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <p>{{eventItem.title}}</p>
  <p>{{tasktItem.title}} - {{tasktItem.status}}</p>
  <p>{{checkListItem.title}}</p>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item in checkListItem.tasks">
        {{item.title}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Event, Task, Checklist } from '../../app/shared/event';
import { Item, ItemType, Priority } from '../../app/shared/item';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  string:string
  array:any[]
  eventItem:Event;
  taskItem:Task;
  checkListItem:Checklist

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.array = []

    this.eventItem = new Event(10, "this is a new event", new Date(), ItemType.Event)
    this.taskItem = new Task(10,  "this is a new task", new Date(), ItemType.Task)
    this.checkListItem = new Checklist(12, "this is a new checklist", new Date(), ItemType.Checklist)

    for (let i = 1; i <= 10 ; i++) {
       let task = new Task(i, `this is task number:${i}`, new Date(), ItemType.Task)
       this.array.push(task)
    }

    this.checkListItem.tasks = this.array

    this.eventItem.description = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eu augue leo. Duis consequat urna quis egestas porttitor. Sed in rhoncus velit. Vivamus euismod vestibulum nisi, eu ornare erat volutpat in. Quisque commodo nisi urna, non porttitor eros porttitor volutpat. Praesent malesuada ultrices enim ut interdum. Ut suscipit sed lorem ac facilisis. Aenean et sapien quis diam hendrerit rhoncus. Praesent ac blandit libero. Duis varius congue lorem sit amet pharetra. Etiam dictum leo eget tincidunt eleifend. Suspendisse volutpat justo augue, vitae pulvinar turpis cursus at."

    this.taskItem.description = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eu augue leo. Duis consequat urna quis egestas porttitor. Sed in rhoncus velit. Vivamus euismod vestibulum nisi, eu ornare erat volutpat in. Quisque commodo nisi urna, non porttitor eros porttitor volutpat. Praesent malesuada ultrices enim ut interdum. Ut suscipit sed lorem ac facilisis. Aenean et sapien quis diam hendrerit rhoncus. Praesent ac blandit libero. Duis varius congue lorem sit amet pharetra. Etiam dictum leo eget tincidunt eleifend. Suspendisse volutpat justo augue, vitae pulvinar turpis cursus at."


  }


}
```

**this is my app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Do you think this is a bug and if it should be fixed anytime soon? I do not remember having a syntax-related error in the past. I cannot really find a workaround. Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you include app.module.ts?

Comment: I just added my app.module.ts. it includes import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'.

Comment: are you having _HomePageModule_ by any chance? i.e. are you using lazy loading?

Comment: no  HomePageModule. this is the error I read in the console : " Property binding ngForIn not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations"   .... "

Comment: Ok..why import CommonModule in the page?

Comment: Also can you confirm your ionic version? I set the tag since you dont seem to be using lazy loading

Comment: I am using ionic 3 and angular 5. I read that I might need to import CommonModule. That is why. I find it strange also

Comment: Remove the imports from both page and module.. I think its not recognizing `ion-item` with angular directive for some reason

Comment: import `HttpClientModule` and add to imports array in your app module if you are using that

Comment: Thanks Suraj. I did remove the imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of checkListItem.tasks">
```

instead of:

```
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item in checkListItem.tasks">
```

**for ... in** loops over properties of *objects*.

**for ...  of** loops over *arrays*.

From Angular docs: [NgForOf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

Comment: it is fixed  this is indeed <ion-item *ngFor="let item in checkListItem.tasks">. Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm glad if I could help ;) Don't forget to mark it as answer if it fixed your problem.